# How to overcome joblib's "TypeError: can't pickle instancemethod objects" on class method?

Tags: scikit-learn

Given a class and 2 methods in it A, B.

I am getting a "TypeError: can't pickle instancemethod objects" when trying to execute the following command while in A:

```
joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(joblib.delayed(self.B)(arg1, arg2, arg3) for arg1 in arg1_values_list)
```

I found several threads on Stackoverflow regarding instancemethod and part of them are even related to joblib, but I still didn't manage to overcome this error.

> EDIT:

The following code:

```
from sklearn.externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
def a(self, x):
    print x
    return x*10

class c(object):
    def b(self):
        Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(
            delayed(a)(self, i) 
            for i in range(10))

test_c = c()

test_c.b()
```

runs ok when normally ran.

but fails when trying to profile using "python -m cProfile"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably safer to only pass Python stateless functions to `joblib.Parallel`. You can try to `import dill` to register pickling support for instance methods: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill (your mileage may vary though).

Comment: I tried moving B out of the class and passing 'self' to it as being done in https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/8ad2f5ea8a01a1f33b0acf78bbe7b95c53a6afa4/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py , and I am now getting "TypeError: can't pickle function objects"... what could be the difference that's causing this please?

Comment: Strange I never had any issue using joblib.Parallel on pure functions. Are you using a lambda function somewhere? Can you please edit your question to include a minimalistic reproduction script that does not depend on external code or data?

Comment: This is unbelievable! 4 hours of debug, and the cause of the problem is cProfile! when it is used, joblib parallel fails.

Comment: Good to know thanks for reporting. Indeed, `cProfile` might be wrapping callables with anonymous functions to count the number of calls.

Comment: Can anyone post the solution regarding cProfiles please?

Comment: What do you mean by "solution regarding cPofile"? Just do not profile when using joblib with `n_jobs > 1`. cProfile cannot profile what's happening in children processes so it's useless to try anyway.

Comment: To use dill and pathos you may find here a good start http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2013/12/05/Parallelism-and-Serialization

Answer (score 2):

Try giving backend="threading", multiprocess is by default and it seems to be crashing. This solved the issue for me